# Missing operand before 'like' operator

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
            try
            {
                DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter =(" Like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' ");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

pleas help to solve this  try to search in DGV

Comment: Please share more details and clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you do are missing something. "dv" should have columns which values we want to filter out with the "like" statement. You are not mentioning the column you want to filter. For example:

```
$"[{columnWeWantToFilter}] Like '%{searchString}%'"
```

Here is a code I just wrote to prove my point (and yes, we could improve many things here, but it's just a fast example I came up with):

```
void Test()
    {
        var searchString = "do";
        var columnWeWantToFilter = "item";
        
        try
        {
            var dv = new DataView(InitializeDataView());
            dv.RowFilter = $"[{columnWeWantToFilter}] Like '%{searchString}%'"; //Before the like we place the column we want to use to filter

            //Here we print it just for testing
            foreach (DataRowView dataRow in dv)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dataRow["item"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    //This code was copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-5.0 just to initialize the DataView

    DataTable InitializeDataView()
    {
        // Create one DataTable with ONE COLUMN.
        var table = new DataTable("table");
        var colItem = new DataColumn("item", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        table.Columns.Add(colItem);

        // Add five items.
        DataRow NewRow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            NewRow = table.NewRow();
            NewRow["item"] = "Item " + i;
            table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
        // Change the values in the table.
        table.AcceptChanges();
        table.Rows[0]["item"] = "cat";
        table.Rows[1]["item"] = "dog";
        table.AcceptChanges();


        return table;
    }
```